# Proving a partial derivative identity

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I'm currently studying for a resit and I've been faced with this partial differentiation question:

If $z = f(y/x)$ show that $$x^2\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}+2xy\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y} + y^2\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2} = 0$$

I can do the partial differentiation parts, but I am stuck from that point. It is late and I am tired so it is very possible I'm missing something glaringly obvious.

Comment: *I can do the partial differentiation parts, but I am stuck from that point.*, you gotta be more specific than this....

Comment: I can work out what d^2z/dx^2, d^2z/dxdy and d^2z/dy^2 are, but I don't know how to use those answers to show what it's asking

Comment: You are pretty much done then. You just have to throw those nonlinear terms in front of the derivatives, add them up, and make sure they are $0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $z=f(y/x)$. Thus,

$$\begin{align}
x^2z_{xx}&=\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)f''(y/x)+\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\left(\frac{2y}{x}\right)f''(y/x) \tag 1\\\\
2xyz_{xy}&=\left(-\frac{2y^2}{x^2}\right)f''(y/x)+\,\,\left(-\frac{2y}{x}\right)f''(y/x) \tag 2\\\\
y^2z_{yy}&=\,\,\,\,\,\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)f''(y/x)\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Adding $(1)-(3)$ yields the desired result!

Answer (score 0):

Factoring... $( x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} )^2 z = 0$. Now, just calculate the first order derivatives.

** EDIT **

More details: $z_x = f' (y/x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (y/x) = - (y/x^2) f'(y/x)$, and $z_y = f' (y/x) \cdot \frac{d}{dy} (y/x) = (1/x) f'(y/x)$, so 
$$
( x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} )^2 z 
= (x \cdot - (y/x^2) f'(y/x) + y \cdot (1/x) f'(y/x))^2 
= [f'(y/x) \cdot ( y/x - y/x ) ]^2
= 0.
$$